# How to trim all non-alphanumeric characters from start and end of a string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some strings that I want to clean up by removing all non-alphanumeric characters from the beginning and end.

It should work on these strings:

```
)&*@^#*^#&^%$text-is.clean,--^2*%#**)(#&^ --->> text-is.clean,--^2

-+~!@#$%,.-"^&example-text@is.clean,--^#*%#**)(#&^ --->> example-text@is.clean
```

I have this regex, which removes them from the whole string:

```
val.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g,'')
```

How would I change it to only remove from the beginning and end of string?

Comment: No, it was a bad example, I fixed it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Modify your current *RegExp* to specify the start or end of string with `^` or `$` and make it greedy. You can then link the two together with an OR `|`.

```
val.replace(/^[^a-zA-Z0-9]*|[^a-zA-Z0-9]*$/g, '');
```

This can be simplified to `a-z` with `i` flag for all letters and `\d` for numbers

```
val.replace(/^[^a-z\d]*|[^a-z\d]*$/gi, '');
```

Comment: Better to use the `+` rather than `*` quantifier. Why replace nothing with nothing?

Comment: val is a jQuery method.  Shouldn't this read "val().replace(...)"?

Comment: @William what leads you to believe that the `val` here is a _jQuery_ method rather than an identifier holding a _String_ primitive?

Comment: Well, for one thing, I created a code example and found that it didn't work as shown in the answer.  I then found "val" in the jQuery documentation.  When I added parens to make it a jQuery method, it worked.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use anchors - `^` and `$`. And also, you would need a quantifier - `*`:

```
val.replace(/^[^a-zA-Z0-9]*|[^a-zA-Z0-9]*$/g,'')
```

Answer (score 4):

Use anchors to match the start and end of the string:

```
val.replace(/^[^A-Z0-9]+|[^A-Z0-9]+$/ig, '')
```

Comment: Your 2nd regex would not function same as the first one. It wouldn't match `@` in the middle, which OP wants.

Comment: +1 for using the `+` rather than `*` quantifier. (It makes no sense to replace zero chars with nothing and is less efficient.)

Answer (score 3):

Use anchors `^` and `$` to match positions before first character and after last character in the string.

```
val.replace(/(^[^A-Za-z0-9]*)|([^A-Za-z0-9]*$)/g, '');
```

You can also shorten your code using `\W` which means non-alphanumeric character, shortcut for `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]` in case you want to keep underscore as well.

```
val.replace(/(^\W*)|(\W*$)/g, '');
```